# bindTextureUnit with Image storage

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I was unable to find any documentation for this but is it possible to do:

`layout(RGBA8, binding = 1) uniform image3D voxels;`

in a fragment shader and bind it in C++ using `glBindTextureUnit(1, myTexture);` ?

Or do I have to query the uniform location manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was unable to find any documentation for this but is it possible to do [...]

Yes.

> Or do I have to query the uniform location manually?

No.

But [`glBindTextureUnit`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTextureUnit.xhtml) is the wrong instruction. An image uniform is linked to a texture object by the [texture image unit](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Images_in_the_context).

In the shader program the the [binding points](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points) can be set:

```c
layout(RGBA8, binding = 1) uniform image3D voxels;
```

this is the equivalent of getting the uniform location for "voxels" and setting its uniform value to "1". Hence the image uniform `voxels`, is associated to  texture image unit "1".

The texture object has to be bound to the corresponding  texture image unit by [`glBindImageTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindImageTexture.xhtml). e.g:

```cpp
glBindImageTexture(1, myTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA8);
```

this instruction binds `myTexture` to  texture image unit 1.

---

Note, `glBindTextureUnit(1, myTexture);` would bind a texture object to a texture unit, which can be use by a corresponding texture sampler uniform. e.g:

```c
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler3D voxels;
```